# Server.Encode / decode not working in production server

Tags: asp.net

I pass a vb.net query string to a page with, depending on the parameter, a spanish character on it, wich works perfectly on the development and testing servers, but not in production.

So, inside the query string I encode the name like this:

```
Server.UrlEncode(name)
```

And even before it gets to load, the server  throws a  "`500 Internal Server Error`"
with this url:

```
http://website/Dir/Page.aspx?num=CEJMEJINMFCEGICCEH&name=Jose+Bonse%c3%b1or+Del+Rosario
```

when I replace the `%c3%b1` for any other normal letter, it works (`%c3%b1` is an "ñ")

Again, its works just fine on the other servers, except on production, I dont even know where to start looking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpServerUtility` class (which "Server" is an instance of in the Page base class) uses ASCII by default to decode and encode URL parameters.  ASCII, of course, is not vast enough to handle other localizations.  To force Unicode, try using `UrlEncodeUnicode` function of the `HttpUtility` class instead...

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(name)
```

Comment: Haha yeah I used to play.  Haven't for a while.  By the way, I just completely changed my answer after looking at Server.UrlEncode in Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that pop to mind although I cannot say that I've actually tested either in this specific case (request string encoding).

First, how is your page encoded?  That is, do you indicate the character sets used?

Second, how is the server computer configured re: localization?  I'd compare the "Regional and Language Options" in the Control Panel on the three computers.

Finally (Ok, that's three) there are localization options in Web.Config.  As is often true, CodeProject has a [great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Internationalization.aspx) on the subject.

Good luck!